# node.js- how to send multiple values ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

my node.js

```
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'html');
 app.engine('.html',require('ejs').__express);  

 app.get('/dashboardList',dash.list);
 app.get('/getDashList',dash.getList);
```

my dashboard.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
   res.render('dashList.html');
  };
exports.getList = function(req, res) {
   fs.readFile('dashList.html', 'utf-8', function(error, data) {
       client.query('select * from spa', function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (error) {
        console.log('error:' + error);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(ejs.render(data,{
             result:result,
             title:'Express'
          }
        }// end else
     });// end query
   });// end fs
}// end getList
```

my dashList.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function listView(){
    alert('listView in');
    $('#output').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/getDashList',
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(result) {
            alert('success');
            alert(typeof (result));
            $(result).each(function(index, item) {
                var output = '';
                output += '<tr>';
                output += '<td>' + item.file_no + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + item.file_name + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + item.file_content + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + item.file_model + '</td>';
                output += '</tr>';
                $('#output').append(output);
              });//end each
          }//end success
      });//end ajax
    }//end listView
   listView();
});
 </script>   
<body>
<table id="output"></table>
   <%=title%>
</body>
```

in body tag <%=title%>-> this is error occurs

error message:title is not defined

On the server side,i want to send multiple values using ajax to dashList.html

if i don't use ajax,it works fine. but i want to ajax.

if my code is not correct i hope that let me know the correct code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashList.html');
};
```

You're rendering dashList.html and not specifying a title. It would be the same if you tried to use a javascript variable that hadn't been declared yet. So do something like this instead:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashList.html', { title: 'Express' });
};
```